# Programmatically "swipe-to-dismiss" an item in a ListView/RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, swipe, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I need to be able to programmatically dismiss an item inside a `RecyclerView` without the user actually swiping (instead I want to dismiss the item when they tap a button in the card). A lot of libraries I've seen only seem to support actual swipes.

I've tried using an existing library and just simulate a `MotionEvent` by creating a swipe on my own programmatically, but this interferes with another horizontal-swipe listener, so I'm wondering how else this could be done, ideally for a `RecyclerView` but if anyone knows how to for a `ListView` instead I can try to adapt that.

I've looked at [this](https://github.com/krossovochkin/Android-SwipeToDismiss-RecyclerView) library as well as others for inspiration but I can't figure out how to trigger the swipes programmatically instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with custom adapter, and call `notifyDataSetChanged` after removing an item from the datalist:

```
private void removeListItem(View rowView, final int position) {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    rowView.startAnimation(anim);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            values.remove(position); //Remove the current content from the array

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh list
        }

    }, anim.getDuration());
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution

Comment: Works for `ListView`, I'll adapt it to `RecyclerView`, thanks

Comment: Closest to a solution I have found. Only problem I have: The ``CardView`` in my ``RecyclerView`` reappears for a split second before the next ``CardView`` is beautifully slid in from below. Any idea on why this is happening? I have tried adjusting the adjusting the postDelayed ``delayMillis`` with no luck.. I am using ``adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`` to achieve the slide up animation of the next card.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the libraries that offer the swipe to dissmis funcionality ad extract the animation part, if im not mistaken its at the *action_up* at the *onTouch()*. Then call it from your onClick of the button.