# How to programmatically initiate a swipe to dismiss with RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, swipe

When I delete an item from a `RecyclerView` I want to show a "swipe" animation, that is that the item is moved sideways off the screen. I believe there is support for "swipe to dismiss" using `ItemTouchHelper`, but this is touch-initiated whereas I want to be able to initiate the swipe programmatically.

I have also tried setting the `RecyclerView` item animator by extending `DefaultItemAnimator`. Using this method I can get items to swipe left and right but unfortunately the gap in the list closes quickly such that the swipe does not finish before the list item gap has closed.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ItemAnimators` offered by [this library](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators). More specifically, your would use their `SlideInLeftAnimator` or `SlideInRightAnimator`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's already answered with external library; probably someone wants to do it with raw java.. I have done it with the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650286/programmatically-swipe-to-dismiss-an-item-in-a-listview-recyclerview#30650628)

The idea is that, you take off the list item view of the `RecyclerView` to be deleted and animate it; and normally remove it from the adapter

```
private void removeListItem(View rowView, final int position) {

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
anim.setDuration(500);
rowView.startAnimation(anim);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        values.remove(position); //Remove the current content from the array

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh list
    }

}, anim.getDuration());
}
```